# Compare two multi-multi-dimensionals-arrays

Tags: php, arrays, compare

I got the following array (shortened ... multiple dot mean that they are data there, both array start at entry 1 until the end.

```
Array
(
    [12U_S_136_15_29_141] => Array
        (
            .....

            [35] => Array
                (
                    [stop_sequence] => 35
                    [stop_id] => 1601394
                )

            .....

            [46] => Array
                (
                    [stop_sequence] => 46
                    [stop_id] => 122052
                )

            [47] => Array
                (
                    [stop_sequence] => 47
                    [stop_id] => 136208
                )

            [48] => Array
                (
                    [stop_sequence] => 48
                    [stop_id] => 128163
                )

        )

    [12U_S_141_57_6_141] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [stop_sequence] => 1
                    [stop_id] => 1601394
                )

            .....

            [12] => Array
                (
                    [stop_sequence] => 12
                    [stop_id] => 122052
                )

            [13] => Array
                (
                    [stop_sequence] => 13
                    [stop_id] => 136208
                )

            [14] => Array
                (
                    [stop_sequence] => 14
                    [stop_id] => 128163
                )

        )

)
```

As you can see, both array end are equal... `35 = 1`, `46 = 12`, ..., `48 = 14`. By equal, I mean the same `stop_id` but will always be diffrent for `stop_sequence` and of course the array entry number.

I want to know how I can compare the entire array against the other so I can know if, here let's say, the second array match the first one at 100% (except we don't look for `stop_sequence` so this can be different. So in this case, both will be mark as "equal", but if let's say the last entry had a different stop_id (entry 48 would be != from the entry 14), the array will be mark as "not equal".

Anyone have a path to lead me ? I keep thinking but do not know how. I've tryed array_compare but this leaded to nothing :\

Thanks

**EDIT**
Nothing can be change to the database. Also, the array need to be created this way (with weird text, ie `12U_S_136_15_29_141`). I can do whatever in PHP.

Comment: StackOutsource.com :) Maybe you should turn the two arrays inside out for comparison like { 1601643:34, 1601643:46, ... }

Comment: @biziclop Good idea there sir. I would then loop to check if all key follow each other ?

Comment: In this form you can probably compare them with some built-in function, or simply with `==`.

Comment: If I use `==`, would it fail if both array contain the same part but not the entire same part? Like in my example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fetch the stop_id in to new array:s and compare thous

here is a useful function

```
    function sub_array($array, $sub_key)
    {
            $new_array = array();
            if(is_array($array) AND $array)
            {
                    foreach($array as $key => $data)
                    {
                            $new_array[$key] = $data[$sub_key];
                    }
            }
            return $new_array;
    }
```

then just compare the arrays

```
if(sub_array($a['12U_S_136_15_29_141'], 'stop_id') == sub_array($a['12U_S_141_57_6_141'], 'stop_id'))
```

or if you know what stop_id that matches:

```
$first_stop_id_list = sub_array($a['12U_S_136_15_29_141'], 'stop_id');
$secound_stop_id_list = sub_array($a['12U_S_141_57_6_141'], 'stop_id');
$matches = array_intersect($first_stop_id_list, $secound_stop_id_list);

if(!$matches)
   echo "No stop_id matches";
else if($first_stop_id_list = $secound_stop_id_list)
   echo "all element was in both";
else if($matches == $first_stop_id_list)
   echo "all element in first was in secound";
else if($matches == $secound_stop_id_list)
   echo "all element in secound was in first";
```

Comment: Thakns for the function. However, my second array will only contain a part of the first one but will match. I guess I'll need to create two key table with `stop_id` and compare. It need to stay in order.

Comment: php have functions for "Set theory", like array_intersect and array_diff

Comment: I don't understand your first else if with one equal ? Will the intersect will match stop_id at the same position ? `2012, 2013` = `2012, 2013` yes but not `2013, 2012`

Comment: sorry, i blam may keyboard, ofcourse it should be == not =, if position isn't relevant, you can use sort()

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll try to play with the idea you came with. But, I think I could create a string with all `stop_id` separated with a commas, ie `2012,2013,2014,2015` and check if this string matches in others. I'll explore your way first